# Connect to SQL Server 2005 with PHP from linux

Tags: sql-server, pdo

I have Windows and Linux servers. SQL Server 2005 is installed on the Windows machine and I want to connect to Windows database from my other Linux server using PHP. Servers are in different locations.

I have tried everything but not successful. Here is my phpinfo output:

```
Configure Command    './configure' '--with-apxs2' '--with-curl=/usr/local/lib' '--with-gd' '--with-ttf' '--with-gettext' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/lib' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/lib' '--with-kerberos' '--with-openssl' '--with-mcrypt' '--with-mhash' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config' '--with-pdo-mysql=/usr' '--with-unixODBC=/usr' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr/local' '--with-pear' '--with-png-dir=/usr/local/lib' '--with-xsl' '--with-mssql=/usr/local/freetds' '--with-pdo-dblib=/usr/local' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/lib' '--with-iconv=/usr/local' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-safe-mode' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-zip' '--enable-wddx'
```

ODBC support, dblib, Mssql are enabled.

There is no firewall on the Windows machine. I have forwarded 1433 port from modem. I am able to connect from Windows sql studio, from WAMP on my machine (local), but not able to connect from PHP :(

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your these files on your Linux server?  (These are taken from an Ubuntu 12.04 server)

/etc/odbc.ini

```
# Define a connection to the MSSQL server.
# The Description can be whatever we want it to be.
# The Driver value must match what we have defined in /etc/odbcinst.ini
# The Database name must be the name of the database this connection will connect to.
# The ServerName is the name we defined in /etc/freetds/freetds.conf
# The TDS_Version should match what we defined in /etc/freetds/freetds.conf
[mssql]
Description             = MSSQL Server
Driver                  = freetds
Database                = MyDatabase
ServerName              = mssql
TDS_Version             = 8.0
```

/etc/odbcinst.ini

```
# Define where to find the driver for the Free TDS connections.
[freetds]
Description     = MS SQL database access with Free TDS
Driver          = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
UsageCount      = 1
```

/etc/freetds/freetds.conf

```
# The basics for defining a DSN (Data Source Name)
# [data_source_name]
#       host = <hostname or IP address>
#       port = <port number to connect to - probably 1433>
#       tds version = <TDS version to use - probably 8.0>

# Define a connection to the MSSQL server.
[mssql]
        host = mssql_server_ip_or_domain_name
        port = 1433
        tds version = 8.0
```

I've read several accounts of the tds version causing problems. It seems like 8.0 words best but I've also seen people say they got things working with 7.5 and 7.0.

And here's an example PDO connection:

```
$pdo = new PDO("dblib:dbname=$database_name;host=$database_server", $temp_username, $temp_password);
```